# Как переменную Translate_points сделать глобальной?

Tags: python, pyqt

выдает такую ошибку name 'Translate_points' is parameter and global. счетчик не работает.
Как сделать результат работы функции доступным для считывания следующей функции?

```
    import random
     def V1_inputf1(Translate_points):
        print(Translate_1,'рандомный глагол')
        Infinitive_input=input("введите инфинитив ",)
        if Infinitive_input==Infinitive[index_Translate]:
            Translate_points += 1
            return Translate_points
        else:
            Translate_points -= 1
            return Translate_points
    def V2_inputf1(Translate_points):
        print(Translate_1,'рандомный глагол')
        Past_Simple_input=input("Введите вторую форму ",)
        global Translate_points
        if Past_Simple_input==Past_Simple[index_Translate]:
            Translate_points += 1
            return Translate_points
        else:
            Translate_points -= 1
            return Translate_points
     def THE_END():
       print("______________________________________________________________________________")
       print("______________________________________________________________________________")  





while Translate_points<15:
    Translate = ['гнуть', 'строить', 'золотить', 'одалживать', 'отправлять', 'тратить', 'разгибаться']
    Infinitive = ["bend", "build", "gild", "lend", "send", "spend", "unbend"]  # Инфинитив
    Past_Simple = ["bent", "built", "gilt", "lent", "sent", "spent", "unbent"]  # Вторая форма
    Participle_2 = ["bent", "built", "gilt", "lent", "sent", "spent", "unbent"]  # Третья форма
    Translate_1=random.choice(Translate)
    print(Translate_1,'рандомный глагол')
    index_Translate=Translate.index(Translate_1)
    print(Infinitive[index_Translate],'-',Past_Simple[index_Translate],'-',Participle_2[index_Translate])

  print(V1_inputf1(Translate_points))
  print(V2_inputf1(Translate_points))
  THE_END()
  print(V2_inputf1(Translate_points))
  print(V1_inputf1(Translate_points))
  THE_END()
```

Comment: и подскажите как удалять предыдущие выводы после ввода чего либо

Comment: Вопрос про удаление вывода непонятен, проиллюстрируйте примером или опишите сценарий действия.

Comment: Ну чтобы очищалась поле вывода, или такое нельзя сделать, чтобы цикл продолжался, а поле после каждого ввода было чистым

Comment: использую pyCharm.

Comment: Вы бы добавили текстовое описание ваших изменений. И прокомментируйте в вопросе, то что просил CrazyElf: `Вопрос про удаление вывода непонятен, проиллюстрируйте примером или опишите сценарий действия.`

Comment: что из этого пример, что вы ожидали и пр

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Выносите все определения функций `def` из кода наружу. Они должны идти сразу после `import`-ов, перед выполняемым кодом. Когда функции описываются прямо внутри кода, такой код невозможно читать.

Далее.

```py
    def V2_inputf1(Translate_points):
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ параметр функции
        print(Translate_1,'рандомный глагол')
        Past_Simple_input=input("Введите вторую форму ",)
        global Translate_points
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ глобальная переменная
        ...
  print(V2_inputf1(Translate_points))
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ передача параметра в функцию
```

Зачем вам глобальная переменная `Translate_points`, если вы и так `Translate_points` передаёте в функцию при её вызове в явном виде? Уберите просто `global Translate_points`, вам это не нужно.

Единственное что нужно сделать - это принимать изменённое значение переменной, которое возвращает функция, и помещать обратно в эту переменную. Примерно так:

```py
Translate_points = V2_inputf1(Translate_points)
print(Translate_points)
```

И так для всех функций, которые изменяют и возвращают.

Comment: Translate__points=0 перед циклом у меня есть, я не внимательно перенес код сюда. и тоже не работает счетчик

Comment: результат работы первой функции, не идет во вторую, а вычисляется сначала, и перед вычислениями переменная снова равна 0

Comment: @Era_of__enlightenment А, всё, понял, дополнил ответ. Вам нужно сохранять то, что возвращает функция.

Comment: так получилось и с третьей связать получилось, столько мучался, из-за нескольких почти одинаковых строк. Теперь вопрос, как сделать вызов рандомной функции, одной из трех, с рабочим счетчиком в цикле.

Comment: третья почти такая же как первая и вторая